# Display multiple columns in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, dropdownbox

I'm using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and I'd like to show a multicolum table as a drop down, so I need the width of the  drop down container to have a different (larger) width than the input itself

Is it possible to do that?

moreover I'd like to show a table with several columns. From the movies example, I saw that in the formatResult function you create a new table for each row.

Would it be possible to include every row in the same table, so that every cells has the same width? I would need to set some template to contain the rows or something like that.

What I want to achieve is a small input to show the code of an entity, and a large dropdown to show several more columns

--

here's a related issue on github: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1314

Comment: Currently unsupported. See https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/270.

Answer (score 8):

***formatresult*** didn't work for me ! But ***templateResult works fine*** like this with  data form PHP in HTML generated (not ajax content).

Here is woorking code for me, I seperate my columns by a pipe char (we could have more than 2 columns) :

**html (from PHP) :**

```
<option value="...">
    column 1 text | column 2 text
</option>
```

**javascript (jQuery) :**

```
$('#selectSubstance').select2({
    templateResult: function(data) {
        var r = data.text.split('|');
        var $result = $(
            '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-3">' + r[0] + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-9">' + r[1] + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
        return $result;
    }
});
```

EDIT 2021-06-28

> If you want the same visual for selected item (closed select), use the same syntax with `templateSelection:`

For example :

```
$('#selectProduct').select2({            
    placeholder: 'Choose a product.',
    templateResult: function(data) {
        var r = data.text.split('| ');
        var result = jQuery(
            '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-3">' + r[0] + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-9">' + r[1] + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
        return result;
    },
    templateSelection: function(data) {
        var r = data.text.split('| ');
        var result = jQuery(
            '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-3">' + r[0] + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-9">' + r[1] + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use Select2 v3.5, here is a workaround:

```js
function formatResultMulti(data) {
  var city = $(data.element).data('city');
  var classAttr = $(data.element).attr('class');
  var hasClass = typeof classAttr != 'undefined';
  classAttr = hasClass ? ' ' + classAttr : '';

  var $result = $(
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6' + classAttr + '">' + data.text + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6' + classAttr + '">' + city + '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
  return $result;
}

$(function() {
  $('#multi').select2({
    width: '100%',
    formatResult: formatResultMulti
  });
})
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #455A64;
}

#multiWrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
}

.def-cursor {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id='multiWrapper'>
  <select id="multi">
    <optgroup class='def-cursor' label='Country' data-city='City'>
      <option data-city="Athens" id="1" selected>Greece</option>
      <option data-city="Rome" "id="2 ">Italy</option>
  <option data-city="Paris " "id="3">France</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: How would one encode that in a json packet above so that option group gets created.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to give my solution which will hopefully help others.

Using Select2 v4 tableish styling and multicolumn search.
This uses local JSON data.

**Quick overview of how this works:**

There are 2 functions.  The `matcher` function and the `formatSelect`.

The `matcher` function is used for the query.  It will check each word of the query to see if there is a match in any of the rows.  Currently set to return any row that matches atleaast 1 word.

The `formatSelect` function is then run once the `matcher` has returned all matching rows (all rows if no query).  `formatSelect` adds header columns on the first row of data if its the first row being rendered.

The table in this case uses bootstrap column widths for structure.

**The code:**

```
var firstEmptySelect = true;

function formatSelect(result) {
    if (!result.id) {
        if (firstEmptySelect) {
            console.log('showing row');
            firstEmptySelect = false;
            return '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3"><b>Client</b></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3"><b>Account</b></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3"><b>Deal</b></div>' +
                    '</div>';
        } else {
            console.log('skipping row');
            return false;
        }
        console.log('result');
        console.log(result);
    }
    return '<div class="row">' +
                 '<div class="col-xs-3">' + result.client_name + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-xs-3">' + result.account_name + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-xs-3">' + result.deal_name + '</div>' +
                 '</div>';      
}

function matcher(query, option) {
    firstEmptySelect = true;
    if (!query.term) {
        return option;
    }
    var has = true;
    var words = query.term.toUpperCase().split(" ");
    for (var i =0; i < words.length; i++){
        var word = words[i];
        has = has && (option.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(word) >= 0); 
    }
    if (has) return option;
    return false;
}

$('#selectAccountDeal').select2({
    data: {!! $deals !!},
    width: '100%',
    templateResult: formatSelect,
    templateSelection: formatSelect,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    matcher: matcher
})
```

**My example JSON data**

```
[{
    "text": "JL - o yea - Testing this deal",
    "id": 4,
    "client_name": "JL",
    "account_name": "o yea",
    "deal_name": "Testing this deal"
}, {
    "text": "JL - test - fj;askld fj",
    "id": 3,
    "client_name": "JL",
    "account_name": "test",
    "deal_name": "fj;askld fj"
}]
```

**HTML for select element**

```
<select id="selectAccountDeal" name="account_deal_id" placeholder="Select your Deal" required>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

**Example of the select2 dropdown**

[image: select2 table view]

Comment: Way to go, it's a good solution, but when I type in text-box to search, it returns one record less than it should return, for instance when I type 'Tech' it should return 4 rows according to the given data, but it returns one row as header and three more rows as result, so the first row is missing. As I figured out there is two `return` in `formatSelect()`, once it creates the header, one record of result is omitted. In fact the header occupies space of the first row. How do you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't had any success yet with having a fixed header row above the columns to act as a typical table header row, but in terms of actually getting the columns out there, I referred to [this feature request on Github](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/270) where user trebuchetty alludes to using bootstrap's grid styles like col-md-6 (bootstrap versions >= 3).

I tried the following in the select2 options and it seems to give good results:

```
formatResult: function(result) {
    return '<div class="row">' +
           '<div class="col-md-6">' + result.name + '</div>' +
           '<div class="col-md-6">' + result.manager + '</div>' +
           '</div>';
},
```

*result* in the above is a reference to an element in the array of items displayed in the dropdown

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle or something like that? I don't get any change to output after using formatResult in version 4.0 +

Comment: `formatresult` didn't work for me ! But `templateResult` works fine, so I posted my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solutions. My select2 version is 4.0.3.

The final presentation look like:
[select2-dropdown-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Zcr.png).

First add the header when select2 dropdown open:

```
    var headerIsAppend = false;
    $('#stock').on('select2:open', function (e) {
        if (!headerIsAppend) {
            html = '<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 0px;">\
                <tbody>\
                <tr>\
                    <td width="20%"><b>药品名称</b></td>\
                    <td width="10%"><b>成本价</b></td>\
                    <td width="20%"><b>供应商</b></td>\
                    <td width="10%"><b>批号</b></td>\
                    <td width="20%"><b>有效期</b></td>\
                    <td width="20%"><b>库存数量</b></td>\
                </tr >\
                </tbody>\
                </table>';
            $('.select2-search').append(html);
            $('.select2-results').addClass('stock');
            headerIsAppend = true;
        }
    });
```

Then

```
templateResult: function (repo) {
            if (repo.medicine) {
                var html = '<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">\
                <tbody>\
                <tr>\
                    <td width="20%">' + repo.medicine.name + '</td>\
                    <td width="10%">' + repo.costPrice + '</td>\
                    <td width="20%">' + repo.vendor + '</td>\
                    <td width="10%">' + repo.batchNum + '</td>\
                    <td width="20%">' + repo.expiredDate + '</td>\
                    <td width="20%">' + repo.quantity + '</td>\
                </tr >\
                </tbody>\
                </table>';
                return $(html);
            }
        },
```

The rest work need to do is adjust the css:

```
.stock .select2-results__option {
  padding: 0px 4px;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Yes this the most eazy way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

refer this it may helpful, here a component to make columns in select2 like structure
https://github.com/suriyagp/Grid-Select

Answer (score 0):

My example (based on Meloman's answer) can maybe help someone else :

```
// HTML
 <select 
    class="form-control select2" 
    data-col0htmldebut="<div class='col-md-6'>" 
    data-col0htmlfin="</div>" 
    data-col1htmldebut="<div class='col-md-2'>" 
    data-col1htmlfin="</div>" 
    data-col2htmldebut="<div class='col-md-4'>" 
    data-col2htmlfin="</div>">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="-1">Text with no column</option>
          <option value="1">Column1__|__Col2__|__Col3</option>
          <option value="2">Column1__|__Col2__|__Col3</option>
 </select>

$("select.select2").select2({
    templateResult: function (data) {
        if (data.element == null) return data.text;


        /**************  Just one column handler **************/

        // __|__ text seperator between each col find ?
        var arrTexteOption = data.text.split('__|__');
        if (arrTexteOption.length <= 1) return data.text;


        /**************  Multi column handler **************/

        // Get select object
        var objSelect = $("#" + data.element.parentNode.id);

        // 4 column handled here
        var arrStyleColDébut = [];
        var arrStyleColFin = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (objSelect.attr('data-col' + i + 'htmldebut'))   arrStyleColDébut.push(objSelect.data("col" + i + "htmldebut"));
            if (objSelect.attr('data-col' + i + 'htmlfin'))     arrStyleColFin.push(objSelect.data("col" + i + "htmlfin"));
        }

        if (arrTexteOption.length != arrStyleColDébut.length) return data.text;

        var $htmlResult = '<div class="row">';
        for (var i = 0; i < arrTexteOption.length; i++)
        {
            $htmlResult += arrStyleColDébut[i] + arrTexteOption[i] + arrStyleColFin[i];
        }
        $htmlResult += "</div>";

        return $($htmlResult);
    },
    templateSelection: function (data) {
        // Selection must display only the first col.
        return data.text.split('__|__')[0];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I using SELECT2 V4. 
Thank to BrinkDaDrink idea. I did some modification and simplified the code.
below is my sample:

```
        var firstEmptySelect = true; // Indicate header was create

        function s2FormatResult(item) {

            if (!item.id) {
                // trigger when remote query
                firstEmptySelect = true; // reset
                return item.text;
            }

            var $container; // This is custom templete container.

            // Create header
            if (firstEmptySelect) {

                firstEmptySelect = false;

                $container = $(
                    '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3"><b>Product ID</b></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3"><b>Product Name</b></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3">' + item.id + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );

            }
            else {
                $container = $('<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3">' + item.id + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-xs-3">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
            }


          return $container
        }
```

[It's look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HSVY.png)